# Alternate between tabs on Safari

Tags: safari, safari-extensions

I'd like to have the same effect of command + tilde - that is, alternate between windows of the same application - but with tabs, in Safari. If possible, I'd like to use the same shortcut.

Is there a way to achieve this?

---

EDIT
By "alternate" I mean alternate stacked tabs, just the same behaviour of command + tild to alternate between applications, that is, I go back to the last tab instead of going to the next. I don't want to cycle through tabs, I always have a million tabs opened, so it's kind of useless to me.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to be able to switch both to the next tab and the previous one. In my answer, Shift+Cmd+[ switches to the previous tab. Is this the result you are looking for?

Comment: No, I want the same behaviour of command + tilde, you know?? It would switch back to the previous tab, where "previous" means the tab I was using before, not the tab on the left! **Stacked** tabs behaviour.

Comment: I see. I don't know if there is a way to do this, but in the meantime you can drag your most commonly used tabs next to each other and use the other keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl-Tab</kbd> is the default key combo to switch the tab in Safari

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear, I updated my question to explain it better

Answer (score 0):

Shift+Command+] and Shift+Command+[ also work. If you have a new enough version of Safari, you can press Shift+Command+\ to enter "tab view" that shows all your tabs next to each other. Press left and right to switch tabs. Press return to open the selected tab. Little dots appear at the bottom of the window to show the number of tabs and where the tab is on the tab bar, you can also click on those.

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear, I updated my question to explain it better